# System vs ShellExecute - Differences?

Tags: c++, winapi

In C++, what are the main differences between `system()` and `shellexecute()`?

In what situations should I use `system()` and `shellexecute()`?

Comment: `ShellExecute` has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: system is standard, shellexecute is not, use the former

Comment: @111111 Why do you say that? Suppose you were writing code that were to run on Windows that wanted to open a URL in the users default browser? Surely `ShellExecute` is the right solution.

Comment: @111: Wrong. When writing Windows code and you're not interested in portability, you should always prefer `ShellExecute`. Only use `system` if you absolutely need to write portable code that will work on multiple platforms. And even then, I'd recommend an `#ifdef` instead of `system`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no such thing in standard C++ as `shellexecute`. So there is no difference.

There's the *Win32* function [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx), but that's a Win32 function, not a C++ standard function like `system`.

`ShellExecute` does a different thing from `system`. `system` is (more or less) equivalent to entering a command on the command line. `ShellExecute` is the equivalent of double clicking a file (or right-clicking and selecting a "verb" from the list).

They really have nothing in common at all.

Comment: I think that if you call `system` control does not return to the program until execution is completed while `ShellExecute` doesn`t wait for completion.

Comment: `ShellExecute` is actually a very powerful function that can do many things. Key to its power is the ability to specify a "verb" as a parameter, which tells the function which action to perform. It is thus somewhat inaccurate to characterize it as behaving in a particular way, as it can be instructed to behave in various ways. This is, of course, key to its power and utility. When writing Win32 code, `ShellExecute` should always be preferred over `system`.

Comment: @CodyGray: But they don't do the same thing. `system` searches the path for the executable. `ShellExecute` must be *told* where the executable is (if you're trying to run one). While `ShellExecute` can run executables, it's just a lot less convenient than running `system` on them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You could simply execute `ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "notepad.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` to launch Notepad. I can't recall anything that requires you to specify a fully-qualified path to something that is on your path.

Comment: @CodyGray: I didn't read anything in the docs that said that it would search the current search path for the executable. I've never used the function, so I can only go by what MSDN says.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `ShellExecute` doesn't even need to be told _what_ the executable is, let alone where it's located. E.g. `ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://stackoverflow.com/", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` will open the default browser. See [KB837633](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837633) for some background info.